# Is there any university in Scandinavia where one can study Traditional Chinese (繁體字)?

Tags: traditional-characters

My question is short:

Is there any university in Scandinavia where one can study the Chinese language using Traditional Chinese characters (繁體字)?

Comment: if you have already studied Chinese Mandarin, just a dictionary or a dictionary web-site like zdic.net needed ? for internet terms, urbandictionary.com is fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to learn  Traditional Chinese characters (繁體字), go to Taiwan.
If you want to learn  Simplified Chinese characters (简体字), go to China Mainland.
And MS office can easily convert those two types of characters for your comparison.
Taiwanese accent sounds pretty the same as PUTONGHUA(Chinese mandarin)

Comment: How does that answer the question?